# Oracle: How to use function based index in container generated jpa query WHERE clause

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, ejb, jpql

We have a  data table where it has a function based index (database is Oracle). But in our Java EE ejb application, system accesses the data using jpa queries.

But in order to force the oracle to use the function based index instead of doing a full table scan, I need a way to tell the jpa container  to generate the sql with the function defined in the index in the WHERE clause of the sql query.

As far as I know, we have to use native queries for creating customizations in the generated queries like that. But in order to use native queries we have to do many code changes. 
Could anyone please suggest any other work around for solving this issue?

**Index:** (We needed to enforce unique constraint for Dev_Id + Dev_Type, but sometimes Dev_Id can be null while Dev_Type can be duplicated.)

```
 (NVL2(Dev_Id, Dev_Id, NULL), NVL2(Dev_Id, Dev_Type, NULL))
```

**Query we need:** (In order to use the index)

```
Select * from some_table where NVL2(Dev_Id, Dev_Id, NULL) = 'some_val';
```

**Container generated query:**

```
Select * from some_table where Dev_Id = 'some_val';
```

Comment: Isn't `NVL2(Dev_Id, Dev_Id, NULL)` redundant? And can't you just add an index on Dev_Id?

Comment: @eaolson our DBA said it didn't work for some valid values, But I am wondering why that happened, because NVL2(Dev_Id, Dev_Id, NULL)  and Dev_Id is basically same. I couldn't get the values which he talked about. I will check this again. thanks.

Comment: @eaolson DBA said we cannot add a unique index like (Dev_Id, NVL2(Dev_Id, Dev_Type, NULL)), because then oracle won't allow NULL values for Dev_Id. That is strange, but I didn't have the time to test it to confirm yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe creating a view and having JPA go through that is an option?

```
 CREATE VIEW SOME_VIEW AS SELECT SOME_TABLE.*,  
    NVL2(Dev_Id, Dev_Id, NULL) AS NVL_DEV_ID FROM SOME_TABLE;


 SELECT * FROM SOME_VIEW WHERE NVL_DEV_ID = ?
```

Or a virtual column on the table that evaluates to the function?

Answer (score 1):

JPA 2.1 includes a `FUNCTION` operator that allows to invoke DB-specific functions:

```
from SomeEntity where function('NVL2', devId, devId, null) = 'some_val';
```

If you don't have JPA 2.1 available but are using Eclipselink >= 2.4, you can also use `FUNCTION`, as it is available as a Eclipselink extension.

If you have Eclipselink 2.3.x, you do not have `FUNCTION`, but you can use the equivalent `FUNC` that is available as a Eclipselink extension.